# Recreating new object

Tags: c#, class, object, instance

so I'm having a very easy to solve ( I think) problem.
I'm making some mini-games, lets say I have game 1, game2, game3.
I can start game1 then after it's done I can start the game from the beginning.
The problem is that when I start the game again when I do game1=new Game1(); it doesn't start from 0, some objects are already asigned to game1 so I obviously get errors.

To clarify a little bit more:
User chooses: Game1,Game2,Game3 --> He chooses Game1 --> CreateGame1(); --> game1=new Game1();
User finishes the game and chooses to enter the game again: CreateGame1() --> game1=new Game1(); here is where the problem is. game1 is defined at the beginning of my class as Game1 game1;

Is there any easy way to solve this or should I remove every item manually?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you paste some of your code? It does sound like you have a static property somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you have some static properties whose values are not reset when a new object is created.  I do not see other reason for this issue.  Anyway, it's difficult to answer the question precisely since you did not post your code.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, yes I believe that was the problem. What can I do with Events? I have a few actions that need to be static, so would that be a problem?

Comment: I think that you can reset your static property values in the constructor.  **BUT**, if you need to reset them, you should definitely be sure that they need to be static.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using static fields in the Game class?

When you create a new instance of a class, all non-static fields are initialized. But static fields are not per-instance, so they keep their value.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using static fields, remember that these are "class level" and don't get "reset" upon a new instance being created.

Answer (score 0):

I think im misunderstanding, because creating a new instance should clear anything that isnt per-defined or in the constructor or static

If im missing the point then try looking into iDisposable